# Clearing cache bug

Tags: 8

I have a problem with a website I'm working on.
When I clear the cache on my local site, the staging breaks.
When I clear the cache there, it works again but this time the local isn't working anymore...

Any ideas what's causing this bug?

I get this as an error message in my terminal for the local site:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "path_alias" entity type does not exist." at .../web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php line 150

We're using version 8.8.2

The database is shared between the local and the live site.

Comment: have you tried `drush updb` ? have you recently updated to core 8.8 and higher? what drupal core version is it? please provide more info

Comment: Any chance you are sharing the db between the two instances?

Comment: You probably need to update your database first. If you have drush : `drush updb`, if you don't you can visit : yoursite.com/update.php

Comment: I've tried updb and the local version works again but when I visit the staging, It's broken again. The db is indeed shared between the two

Comment: You can't share a db between different codebases. You need to take a copy of the db and use that for your local development.

Comment: Sharing a db is a bad practice, you really need to have 2 db.

Comment: If by sharing a database you mean more than one site (on different code/branches) is using the same database (instead of multiple databases in one sql instance), this would be bad practice. It will cause configs to keep shifting and reporting the wrong schema updates in the database, for starters, depending on which site is reading the database.

Comment: If your provider only supports one "schema" (often called Database), then you have to use table prefixes to have two separate Drupal "databases".  This is done with the 'prefix' key in the database information defined in your settings.php.  Note you can use a setting.local.php file on your dev site to define a different database.  DON'T check this in to your code repo.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem but just in case.. If you are using two databases AND using a shared Memcache, you can also see issues like this.  In this case, you need to add a memcache key per site to make sure they are not sharing this part of cache.

Comment: It is not a good idea to share a database among different environments. This is kind of a known issue starting from Drupal 8.8.0 since path_alias is converted to revisionable entities. Please refer https://www.drupal.org/node/3013865. As @sohali suggested update you database either using drush updb or update.php.